# Fan is on constantly after recent update

Tags: updates, services, fancontrol

Prior to a recent update Fancontrol started at boot, and everything was fine.

Now after the fan doesn't stop. To solve it, every time I turn on the PC I have to set up pwmconfig again. Then I have to run

```
sudo fancontrol
```

Which makes the fans controlled as they should be. I don't understand why I have to go through all this on every boot. The pwmconfig part in paticular puzzles me. I have the file set up (/etc/fancontrol) but if I try running fancontrol before pwmconfig it says:

"Device name of hwmon1 has changed

Configuration appears to be outdated, please run pwmconfig again"

Comment: Do you have to run sudo pwmconfig everytime before /etc/fancontrol?

Comment: Yes, every time.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, just reinstalling it fixed it:

```
    sudo apt-get purge fancontrol && sudo apt-get install fancontrol
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first web search hit for this error, the upstream bug is:  https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/227

The corresponding ubuntu bug has been open for ten years:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lm-sensors-3/+bug/576602

The arch advice:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control#Device_Paths_have_Changed_in_%2Fetc%2Ffancontrol

The problem is that the hwmon device numbers can change every boot, and pwmconfig / fancontrol do not handle it.  The workaround I've used is specifying the kernel module load order via /etc/modprobe.d/fancontrol.conf as described in detail in the ubuntu and arch links.  Mine contains:

softdep nct6775 pre: amdgpu
softdep k10temp pre: nct6775
softdep asus_wmi pre: k10temp
softdep hid_logitech_hidpp pre: k10temp

Note that you need to specify the order for everything in:

grep -H . /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon*/name